# Magento 2 - How to add a custom column in customer grid

Tags: magento2, column, customer-grid

I am using below code to add a column in customer grid in admin.

**/app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="magcustomer_customer_approve" class="Namespace\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Showisapproved">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Approved</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">51</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**/app/code/Namespace/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Showisapproved.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Showisapproved extends Column
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param ContextInterface   $context           
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory   
     * @param array              $components        
     * @param array              $data              
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = 0;//Value which you want to display
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

**magcustomer_customer_approve** is customer attribute created using below code.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magcustomer_customer_approve', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Is Approved',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1001,
            'position' => 1001,
            'system' => 0,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'adminhtml_only'=>1,
            'default'=>0
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magcustomer_customer_approve')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
```

1. If I don't use **Magecoder\Magcustomer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Showisapproved**, the custom column comes blank.

[image]

But if I use then I need to fetch using customer model in function **prepareDataSource** because variable **$dataSource** does not contain value of custom column. Is it possible to show values without fetching data again?

2. Also when filter is used a SQL error is generated.

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'magcustomer_customer_approve' in 'where clause'
> , query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` WHERE (`magcustomer_customer_approve
> ` = '1') AND (`magcustomer_customer_approve` = '1') AND (`magcustomer_customer_approve` = '1') AND (
> `magcustomer_customer_approve` = '1') AND (`magcustomer_customer_approve` = '1')
> ```

Comment: have a look here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126534/add-custom-column-to-customer-admin-grid/126711#126711  may be this can help

Answer (score 7):

### Solution for Magento 2.1

- Add the attribute to the customer grid index:

  **`etc/indexer.xml`**

  ```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
      <indexer id="customer_grid">
          <fieldset name="customer">
              <field name="magcustomer_customer_approve" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
          </fieldset>
      </indexer>
  </config>
  ```

  Note that the "indexer" and "fieldset" elements only have the "id" and "name" attributes respectively. The structure is merged into the existing indexer.
- Mark the attribute as "used in grid"

  In the installer:

  ```
          'is_used_in_grid' => true,
  ```

  otherwise you will get another SQL error during indexing, because the indexer looks for the column in the `customer_entity` main table:

  > SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.magcustomer_customer_approve' in 'field list'

Comment: what is the solution for magento 2.2? same?

Comment: I have a varchar attribute in the customer field,in this method there is no error comes, but the sorting have some problem.

Answer (score 5):

Finally got the solution : We need to create **indexer.xml file** in **/etc/di** folder.

Main thing is **view_id** in view_id we need to pass "**coloumn_name**" which we need to show in grid.

For example here i need to display **nickname** so i have passed "**nickname**" in **view_id**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid" view_id="nickname" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
        <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection"
                  provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
            <field name="nickname" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

**It works on Magento 2.1.4**

Comment: Solution works fine but while export getting error.

Comment: @ChiragPatel - Yes that is correct , because i haven't amended/work around on any export functionality so , you need to override order export functionality in this custom module and need to work around for the same

Comment: Thanks, if you have any idea or example how to override export functionality then please share.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to add following code..
Step1:Create file your_module/etc/indexer.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
<indexer id="customer_grid" view_id="dummy" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
    <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
        <field name="<your_attribute>" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
    </fieldset>
</indexer>
```

Now you need to below command:

run command : php bin/magento indexer:reindex

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom column in the customer grid Using the below way.

==> please create the first module and follow the below step
==> Now we used to the plugin, please create the file at the below location.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="grid_customs_column" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\GridCustomerJoinCollection" sortOrder="5" />
    </type>
</config>
```

==>Now create the plugin to join the table with your collection and return the collection and create the file at below location

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/GridCustomerJoinCollection.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class CollectionPool
 */
class GridCustomerJoinCollection
{

    public static $table = 'customer_grid_flat';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'sales_order'; // My custom table
    /**
     * Get report collection
     *
     * @param string $requestName
     * @return Collection
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function afterGetReport(
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
     $collection,
     $requestName
 ) {
     if($requestName == 'customer_listing_data_source')
     {
         if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {

            $leftJoinTableName = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$leftJoinTable);

            $collection
                ->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    ['co'=>$leftJoinTableName],
                    "co.customer_id = main_table.entity_id",
                    [
                        'customer_id' => 'co.customer_id',
                        'custom_filed'=> 'co.custom_filed'
                    ]
                );
                /* return data with left join customer_id from sales_order and custom_filed*/

            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);

            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where)->group('main_table.entity_id');;

            /*echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();die;*/

        }

     }
     return $collection;
 }
}
```

==> Now create the below folder and file and add the columns at the 
**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
       <column name="custom_filed">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">999</item>
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Customer Custom Column</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
   </columns>
</listing>
```

===> **Now please chek and confirm**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above solution but not working

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
<indexer id="customer_grid" view_id="dummy" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
    <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
        <field name="is_approved" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
    </fieldset>
</indexer>
```

But not working So first my question is how can we override `indexer.xml`?

After I checked you the solution you source `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection` and in `Magento_Customer/etc/indexer.xml` using `Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source` and this showing error while indexing.

So I think we don't need any think only apply customer attribute

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_approved', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Approved',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'value' => 0,
            'default' => 0,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'position' => 90,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
        ]);
```

So need 'is_used_in_grid' => true and in di.xml add

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source" type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" />
```

Or

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source" type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" />
```

And It's working

Answer (score -1):

Here is Solution. Let me know if it works. It works for me like a charm.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237030/63460