# Magento 2: Add custom attributes to customer grid

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I want to add a custom attribute to the admin customer grid. For that, I have added two attributes using ui_component.

The columns show up in the grid but without data from `customer_grid_flat` (because Magento 2 uses a flat grid table for retrieving data to the grid).

I found the following answer on StackExchange:

[add a custom column in customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126820/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-column-in-customer-grid)

According to that, I added an `indexer.xml` file to my custom module:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid" view_id="customer_dummy" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
        <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
            <field name="webshop" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
            <field name="aktiv" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

and executed `php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`.

Now, I face two different errors in two different conditions:

1. Please note above indexer attribute `view_id`. it is **customer_dummy** (Which is default to native customer module). if I use the same `view_id` name in my custom module I get error **Customer grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping**
2. If I use a different `view_id` name and execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid` then it shows **view_id (in my case it just `dummy`) view does not exist.**

Answer (score 6):

Leaving out `view_id` seems to work:

```
<indexer id="customer_grid">
```

This way, the XML will be merged into the existing indexer instead of defining a new indexer.

Comment: I had the same issue, and your solution helped me to fix the problem. But in my case, I also have this view_id="dummy" in indexer.xml. but this view_id has always been there since I installed my custom extension, and the error wasn't there in the beginning. So I wonder why this view_id  suddenly became a problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to that, you can added an indexer.xml file to your custom module:

```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
<indexer id="customer_grid" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
    <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
        <field name="account_number" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="varchar"/>            
    </fieldset>
</indexer>
```

Must be check your attribute datatype varchar or text etc..

Need to 'is_used_in_grid' => true and in di.xml add

```
 <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source" type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" />
```

OR

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source" type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection" />
```

And It's working.