# Magento 2 Dummy view does not exist?

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

When I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and when task finished, at the last line, it shows

[image]

This also happened if I run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

and reindex always failed with

```
dummy view does not exist
```

---

If I go to Admin -> system -> index management, I'll see this error,

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): dummy view does not exist.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): dummy view does not exist.
#0 /public/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(238): Magento\Framework\Mview\View->load('dummy')
#1 /public/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(276): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->getView()
#2 /public/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(180): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->isScheduled()
#3 /public/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Ui/DataProvider/Indexer/DataCollection.php(51): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->isScheduled()
#4 /public/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(688): Magento\Indexer\Ui\DataProvider\Indexer\DataCollection->loadData(false, false)
#5 /public/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(284): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->load()
#6 /public/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid.phtml(51): 

Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getSize()
.......
```

Comment: Do you have any custom indexer's defined?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn Yes I have some custom indexers.

Comment: I have updated the question. Admin -> system -> index management gives me this error too.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145155/magento-2-add-custom-attributes-to-customer-grid

Comment: @DouglasRadburn Thanks, it solved my problem. appreciated.

Comment: Will quickly add it as a solution incase anyone else stumbles across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this is probably related to a misconfigured custom indexer.  Take a look at [Magento 2: Add custom attributes to customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145155/magento-2-add-custom-attributes-to-customer-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency `<module name="Magento_Indexer" />` to your `etc/module.xml`, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_MyIndexerModule">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Indexer" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And make sure that the `id` in your `etc/mview.xml` is identical to the `view_id` in your `etc/indexer.xml`