# Add custom attribute customer

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, custom

I want to add a custom attribute to my customer. For now I have this : (on magento 2.2.4)

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $customerSetupFactory;
private $attributeSetFactory;

public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
{
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "customer_bonus");

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_bonus', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Customer Bonus',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'system' => false,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_bonus')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms'=>['adminhtml_customer']
        ]);

    $attribute->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}

But there's nothing on my backend, I want have something like this result : [Magento 2 - How to add a custom column in customer grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126820/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-column-in-customer-grid)

And **CustomerSetupFactory** is not find in PHP Storm. I tried

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

but nothing change.

Edit : the class is found with setup:di:compile dans after if I do setup:upgrade it's not found anymore.

Comment: Factories are service classes that instantiate non-injectable classes, that is, models that represent a database entity. They create a layer of abstraction between the ObjectManager and business code.

Comment: they are an automatically generated class type.

Comment: Please try reindeing

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Reidexer didn't change it, do you have another idea ?

Comment: And you need to update the config.xml file also

Answer (score 0):

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
 {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
   * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
  */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attributename', [
            'type'      => 'int',
            'backend'   => '',
            'label'     => 'Label',
            'input'     => 'text',
            'source'    => '',
            'visible'   => true,
            'required'  => false,
            'default'   => '',
            'frontend'  => '',
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'unique'    => true,
            'system' => 0,
        ] );

    //add attribute to attribute set
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'sap_id')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();
    $setup->endSetup();
   }     
 }
}
```

This may help you out

Comment: Where does this class is suppose to go ?

Comment: The install data or update data of setup scripts is useful to add a new attribute to the ui forms.